# Write into a file in S3 directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a requirement where I need to write a long String log for each execution of my lambda function, this String is basically log having record of failed and success cases.
as this code is for lambda its not possible to create file in a physical location like local file directly and upload to s3. but I need to directly create a file and write the String in one go.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda functions can write data to the `/tmp/` directory. There is a 512MB limit, so delete any files before your Lambda function exits so that it is clear for the next function execution.

You can therefore create a 'local' file and upload it to Amazon S3.

Alternatively, you can use the Amazon S3 API to create an object (`PutObject()`) while specifying the `Body` content without creating an actual file. This might be easier for you.

By the way, if your Lambda function prints output, it will automatically be captured by the Lambda function and stored in CloudWatch Logs. It will be intermixed with other messages from Lambda (eg showing the amount of memory used), but it's an easy way to log information.

Comment: (Thanks @jarmod -- late night = typos!)

Comment: You're welcome. Probably just need more coffee!